# relsize in footnote leads to too-small font size

Tags: footnotes, scalebox, relsize

I use `relsize` to create a pretty version of the string "C++". This produces warnings when put into `footnote`s or `small` environments, because the result would be "too small". How can I prevent this without having to resort to a different macro for those situations?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\cpp{\texorpdfstring{\protect C\nobreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}\textbf{++}\xspace}}{C++}}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\cpp\ works

foobar\footnote{\cpp\ produces warning}

\chapter{two \cpp}

\end{document}
```

The warning produced is:

```
Package relsize Warning: Font size 5.20834pt is too small.
(relsize)                Using 6.0pt instead on input line 18.
```

I have tried using `\scalebox{.5}{\textbf{++}}` instead of `relsize`. This works nicely for the footnote, but then the command cannot be used as part of a chapter-title anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation one can find

> These limits are controlled by the commands \RSsmallest and
>   \RSlargest, which get set automatically when relsize.sty is loaded,
>   but you can redefine them to other length values:

Which leads to

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\RSsmallest{5pt}
\def\cpp{\texorpdfstring{\protect C\nobreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}\textbf{++}\xspace}}{C++}}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\cpp\ works

foobar\footnote{\cpp\ produces warning}

\chapter{two \cpp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had thought 6pt was a LaTeX wide general lower limit or something like that, so I didn't look into the `relsize` documentation. Your solution works perfectly!